# Add additional item to an item in model class array list

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin

I have a data class

```
@Parcelize
data class PublicationPageModel(
    @SerializedName("pageNumber")
    val pageNumber: Int,
    @SerializedName("content")
    val content: String
): Parcelable
```

I already added items to the array like this:

```
private var publicationPageModel: ArrayList<PublicationPageModel> = arrayListOf()

publicationPageModel.add(PublicationPageModel(finalPageNumber, fileContent))
```

Now, I want to add additional item to the fileContent already in the model above ↑

Say add a string "hello" to each of the **content** in the model

E.g if I have:

```
- PageModel("1", "content1")
- pageModel("2", "content2")
```

Now I want to have:

```
- PageModel("1", "hello content1")
- PageModel("2", "hello content2")
```

How to do this please?

Comment: The quickest code snippet comes to my mind is something like this:
`publicationPageModel.map { it.apply { fileContent. prependIndent("hello ") } }`

Comment: App crashed while doing this @JeelVankhede

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add new value but only 1 String affected. Just append new value. Change the `fileContent` to `var` type.

```
private var fileContent = "content"
private var publicationPageModel: ArrayList<PublicationPageModel> = arrayListOf()

fileContent = "hello $fileContent"
publicationPageModel.add(PublicationPageModel(finalPageNumber, fileContent))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [MessageFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/icu/text/MessageFormat).

```
private var fileContent = "content1"
private var publicationPageModel: ArrayList<PublicationPageModel> = arrayListOf()

publicationPageModel.add(PublicationPageModel(finalPageNumber, MessageFormat.format("Hello {0}", fileContent)))
```

You could event put that "Hello {0}" in [String resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) and when you need it retrieve it from there.

Comment: Works but call is for API level 24 and above.

Comment: What API level do you need?

Comment: My min is 19 (API 19)

Comment: Than you can use `String.format("Hello %s", fileContent)` instead of MessageFormat.